# What's the difference of `/etc/modules-load.d` and `/etc/modules`?

Tags: kernel-modules, startup, etc

I red the introduction of them and found that, they both deal with module loading during boot time.

So, what's the difference of these two different configuation ways?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In distributions where `systemd` is **not** available, *SysV* init scripts load modules listed in `/etc/modules` or `/etc/modules.conf` (from the kmod job).

In distributions where `systemd` **is** available, [`systemd-modules-load.service`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-modules-load.service.html) loads kernel modules from static lists in these files:

- `/etc/modules-load.d/*.conf`
- `/run/modules-load.d/*.conf`
- `/usr/lib/modules-load.d/*.conf`

Comment: In [Ubuntu doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Loadable_Modules), as said, Ubuntu uses `/etc/modules` to config loadable modules. And it didn't mention the `/etc/modules.conf` file. Is the doc out-dated or that's the way Ubuntu uses?

Comment: Different distributions use different way to implement this. In Ubuntu this is /etc/modules.

Comment: @nn0p so in basic there is no difference. Just in the way how it is handled.

Comment: At least nowadays, a SysV-based Debian 12 system honours `/etc/modules-load.d/*.conf`, too.

Comment: If I recall correctly, `/etc/modules.conf` is a very old name for what eventually became `/etc/modprobe.conf`, and then `/etc/modprobe.d/*.conf`. That was *way* back, in the era of 1.2 or 2.0 kernel series I think.